# Consulta em SQL com data inicial e data final

Tags: sql

Galera, preciso consultar alguns valores em uma tabela, tenho que trazer os valores do dia 23/02/2016 até o dia 23/02/2018, tentei fazer em SQL mas não deu tão certo, código abaixo:

```
SELECT u.nome, un.descricao, (SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT(mc.id_marcacao_consulta)),0) 
                             FROM marcacao_consulta AS mc 
                             WHERE mc.id_usuario = u.id_usuario 
                               AND mc.id_status = 0
                               AND mc.data_cadastro BETWEEN "2014-03-08" AND "2018-03-08") AS total_marcacao, (SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT(mc.id_marcacao_consulta)),0) 
                             FROM marcacao_consulta AS mc 
                             WHERE mc.id_usuario = u.id_usuario 
                               AND mc.id_status <> 0
                               AND mc.ultima_atualizacao BETWEEN "2014-03-08" AND "2018-03-08") AS total_atendimento 
FROM usuario AS u 
    INNER JOIN usuario_nivel AS un ON u.id_usuario_nivel = un.id_usuario_nivel
WHERE u.ativo = 1 
HAVING total_marcacao <> 0 
   AND total_atendimento <> 0 
ORDER BY u.nome
```

Comment: Qual erro aparece?

Comment: é o seguinte, eu esqueci de mencionar, mas preciso também de uma hora específica, que é das 7h as 13h, mas quando coloco a hora, ele retorna o mesmo valor desse código (esse código da dúvida é sem a hora), então, suspeito que tenha algo errado aí

Comment: Os dados dessa coluna estão em qual formato?

Comment: timestamp edson

Comment: timestamp edson

Comment: Tenta converter os valores em Unix e realizar a operação.

Comment: qual base de dados está usando ?

Comment: Funções de Data mudam conforme o SGBD , informe o mesmo.